# Parsing JSON Array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm attempting to read a JSON array from my php generated file at www.tiritium.com/standings.php and it works just fine on Android but I cannot get it to read out of the file. It opens it properly but I can't get get the NSDictionary into a NSArray.

```
 //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* latestNames = [json objectForKey:@"name"]; //2

    NSLog(@"name: %@", latestNames); //3
```

I've narrowed down the error to //2 but I can't seem to figure out what is going on. I'm not sure if it is with how my data is being output from the script or with my code in the app itself.

```
2013-08-14 16:39:51.992 Derby Days[7951:c07] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a297b0
2013-08-14 16:39:51.993 Derby Days[7951:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a297b0'
```

Is the error message I am receiving.

Answer (score 7):

Read the exception

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector
```

The root of your JSON is an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file represents an array, not a dictionary. If you need to get an array of names out of it, you use key value coding like `NSArray *names = [json valueForKey:@"name"];`. This will give you an array of `NSString`s.